# Get absolute path from a fd of an AF_UNIX socket in kernel module

Tags: c, struct, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

Given a file descriptor, I need to get its absolute path whether it is a regular file or a `AF_UNIX` socket. The code at [How can I get a filename from a file descriptor inside a kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250078/how-can-i-get-a-filename-from-a-file-descriptor-inside-a-kernel-module) works for regular files but with `AF_UNIX` sockets I get something like this `"socket:[12345]"` instead of the absolute path "/tmp/.X11-unix/X0".

```
struct sockaddr_un {
                    unsigned short   sun_family;    // AF_UNIX
                    char            sun_path[108];  // pathname
                    };
```

Comment: Because it is not a regular file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`netstat -x` shows the full pathnames for unix sockets, by consulting `/proc/net/unix`, which is populated by `unix_seq_show` in `net/unix/af_unix.c`. See here how it is done:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/unix/af_unix.c?v=4.1#L2252