# What is the alternative for 'fcheck_files()' to get absolute path by file descriptor in a kernel module?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, absolute-path

In a kernel module, we use **fcheck_files()** to get *files_struct* which further can be used to get *absolute path* by *descriptor*, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8250940/2706918) for example. The problem with this function is that, It returns *NULL* if provided *descriptor* is for either *empty directory* or a *file*.

Is there any alternative way to get *absolute path* by *fd* for a *file* and/or *empty directory* in a *kernel module*?